# Server Validation in angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

i'm using ruby on rails in my backend and angularjs in my client side.

here's a scenario i input same email in my form so in my console response a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and said 'email was use'. it means my validation was good and working properly in my backend.

my question is how can u get that response and put that in my view so user can see that email was already in use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular's `$http` service, getting the status code of the response is simple, just access `res.status` from one of your factories/services:

```
$http.get(`/route/${id}/foo.json`).then(function(res){
    callback(res)
}).catch( (error) => { console.log(error) })
```

If you want to get that into a controller, I suggest using a callback function like this:

```
someFactory.get($scope.id, function(data){
    console.log("data.status");
})
```

Comment: yeah whichever route you have set up in your backend... Hope it worked